# My variables for my python camel game aren't udating

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a freshman in a computer science degree and I was given this assignment to complete this camel game. I can't seem to find a way for the variables to update when checking the status after moving. They always print miles traveled is 0 and the natives are -20 miles behind. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!
Here is my code.

```
# The comments are from my friend who helped me fix the while loop from repeating over and over

def main ():
    global executed
    executed = 1
    if executed == 1: # This will only show the intro once
        print("Welcome to Camel!")
        print("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi desert.")
        print("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down!")
        print("Survive your desert trek and out run the natives.")
    global done  # Add global next to a variable if you're calling it from outside the function
    executed = 0

main()

done = False
while not done:

    # Game variables
    miles_traveled = int(0)
    thirst = int(0)
    camel_tiredness = int(0)
    native_distance = int(-20)
    canteen_drinks = int(3)

    print("A. Drink from your canteen.")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed.")
    print("C. Ahead full speed.")
    print("D. Stop for the night.")
    print("E. Status check.")
    print("Q. Quit.")

    user_choice = (input("What is your choice? "))
    # Quit the game
    if user_choice.upper() == "Q":
        done = True
        print("Quitting...")
    # Status check
    elif user_choice.upper() == "E":
        print("Miles traveled:", miles_traveled)
        print("Drinks in Canteen:", canteen_drinks)
        print("The natives are", native_distance, "miles behind you.")
    # Stopping for the night
    elif user_choice.upper() == "D":
        camel_tiredness = int(0)
        print("Your camel is happy.")
        import random
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
        print("The natives are", native_distance, "miles behind you.")
    #Full speed
    elif user_choice.upper() == "C":
        thirst += int(1)
        camel_tiredness += int(1)
        import random
        miles_traveled += random.randint(10, 20)
        print("You have traveled", miles_traveled, "miles.")
        import random
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
    # Moderate speed
    elif user_choice.upper() == "B":
        import random
        miles_traveled += random.randint(5, 12)
        print("You have traveled", miles_traveled,"miles.")
        thirst += int(1)
        camel_tiredness += int(1)
        import random
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
     # Drinking from canteen
    elif user_choice.upper() == "A":
        if canteen_drinks >= 1:
            print("You have taken a sip from your canteen")
            print("You have", canteen_drinks - int(1), "sips left in your canteen.")
        elif canteen_drinks == 0:
            print("You are out of water.")
    # The other stuff at the end
    if thirst > 4 < 6:
        print("You are thirsty.")

    if thirst > 6:
        print("You have died of thirst!")
        done = True

    if camel_tiredness > 5 < 8:
        print("Your camel is tired.")

    if camel_tiredness > 8:
        print("Your camel has died.")

    if native_distance >= 0:
        print("The natives have caught you.")
        done = True

    if native_distance >= -15:
        print("The natives are getting close!")

    if miles_traveled >= 200:
        print("You have won and got away from the natives!")
        done = True

    import random
    oasis = random.randint(0, 20)

    if oasis == 20:
        print("You have found an oasis.")
        thirst = 0
        camel_tiredness = 0
```

Comment: You're resetting `miles_traveled` to zero on every run of your `while` loop. Should you be?

Answer (score 2):

Your variables should be out of the while loop in order not to get the same values over and over and also you should have update canteen_drinks variable eachtime.

**Updated code**

```
def main ():
    global executed
    executed = 1
    if executed == 1: # This will only show the intro once
        print("Welcome to Camel!")
        print("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi desert.")
        print("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down!")
        print("Survive your desert trek and out run the natives.")
    global done  # Add global next to a variable if you're calling it from outside the function
    executed = 0

main()
import random

done = False

miles_traveled = int(0)
thirst = int(0)
camel_tiredness = int(0)
native_distance = int(-20)
canteen_drinks = int(3)
while not done:

    # Game variables


    print("A. Drink from your canteen.")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed.")
    print("C. Ahead full speed.")
    print("D. Stop for the night.")
    print("E. Status check.")
    print("Q. Quit.")

    user_choice = (input("What is your choice? "))
    # Quit the game
    if user_choice.upper() == "Q":
        done = True
        print("Quitting...")
    # Status check
    elif user_choice.upper() == "E":
        print("Miles traveled:", miles_traveled)
        print("Drinks in Canteen:", canteen_drinks)
        print("The natives are", native_distance, "miles behind you.")
    # Stopping for the night
    elif user_choice.upper() == "D":
        camel_tiredness = int(0)
        print("Your camel is happy.")
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
        print("The natives are", native_distance, "miles behind you.")
    #Full speed
    elif user_choice.upper() == "C":
        thirst += int(1)
        camel_tiredness += int(1)

        miles_traveled += random.randint(10, 20)
        print("You have traveled", miles_traveled, "miles.")
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
    # Moderate speed
    elif user_choice.upper() == "B":
        miles_traveled += random.randint(5, 12)
        print("You have traveled", miles_traveled,"miles.")
        thirst += int(1)
        camel_tiredness += int(1)
        native_distance += random.randint(7, 14)
     # Drinking from canteen
    elif user_choice.upper() == "A":
        if canteen_drinks >= 1:
            print("You have taken a sip from your canteen")
            canteen_drinks = canteen_drinks - int(1) # you should update the centeen_drinks
            print("You have", canteen_drinks, "sips left in your canteen.")
        elif canteen_drinks == 0:
            print("You are out of water.")
    # The other stuff at the end
    if thirst > 4 < 6:
        print("You are thirsty.")

    if thirst > 6:
        print("You have died of thirst!")
        done = True

    if camel_tiredness > 5 < 8:
        print("Your camel is tired.")

    if camel_tiredness > 8:
        print("Your camel has died.")

    if native_distance >= 0:
        print("The natives have caught you.")
        done = True

    if native_distance >= -15:
        print("The natives are getting close!")

    if miles_traveled >= 200:
        print("You have won and got away from the natives!")
        done = True

    oasis = random.randint(0, 20)

    if oasis == 20:
        print("You have found an oasis.")
        thirst = 0
        camel_tiredness = 0
```